# Enable/Disable jQuery UI sortable at runtime via drag and drop (jsFiddle example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a question for the jQuery gurus among you.

**Scenario**

I'm building a web app that (among other things) allows users to sort cards inside of large table. One feature of this table is a bin that is fixed to the top of the table, but "pinned" to the rows at the same time. It allows users to place cards in a bin that associated with a column, but not a row.

Here is a [stripped down jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/263/) (which was a pain to make) to show you what I mean.

**Problem**

The problem is, if you **scroll down a ways** in the table and then try to drag a card from table into the bin, it doesn't usually work. What happens instead is that card gets placed in the table cell "behind" the bin that the user can't see. Hope that makes sense.

**Question and Plan of Attack**

I'm thinking the best way to solve this issue is to somehow disable dropping in all of the cells in the table except the bin as soon as the user mouses over the bin. That way the card will be sure to land in the bin and not in the table cell behind the bin.

Do you agree? Is there a better way to fix the problem?

**Notes**

You may see my implementation and wonder why I'm implementing things the way I am. (Such as why I'm using table cells instead of divs for the bin, the top row, and the left column.) Unfortunately, I can't completely explain why I chose the implementation I did, but realize I am operating under a number of constraints this example does not show. So... I'm open to advice on how to improve the layout, but please don't answer this question with "Well, why don't you set things up this *'this'* way instead and then you won't have to deal with the issue, because odds are your suggested setup won't work for me for some reason.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks a ton to anyone who answers!

Comment: @zod, I'm using the latest version of Chrome, but the issue appears in Firefox as well (I'm not even bothering to test IE :) ). Also, it's important to note that you must **scroll down** before you see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/299/embedded/result/)):

```
$('#binRow').mouseenter(function() {
    $('tr:not("#binRow") td.card-holder')
        .removeClass('card-holder')
        .addClass('disabled-card-holder');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.disabled-card-holder')
        .removeClass('disabled-card-holder')
        .addClass('card-holder');
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Majid! That is really close. However, the problem with that (I think) is that when you click on a card inside the bin the drag it out into the table, the bin's class is still set to disabled and so the card can't be dropped into the table.

Comment: I changed some styles so that you can see what I mean: card-holders have a red background and disabled-card-holders have a grey background. Once the mouse enters the bin, the other card-holders are never re-enabled. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/286/

Comment: I had a `.` missing in the second callback, which I fixed, but still no luck. I don't know what is preventing drops on lower rows. Link to fixed dot: http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/299/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes I caught that too after my last comment. I'm still messing with it. I'll comment if I get a fix figured out. +1 for suggesting changing the drop class and providing an example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was able to get it working by checking for each container's scroll location: http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/310/

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Congrats! My answer only goes part of the way; were I you, I would have posted my answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Well... if you count the comments your answer is complete. :) But you're right. I probably should have.